# Detecting when an armor stand gets hit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I am creating a datapack which requires the use of armor stands. However, the main issue here is that I don't know how to detect when an armor stand gets hit. Most mobs, including the armor stand, have the property `HurtTime:0` which indicates how many ticks (up to 20) before it can receive more damage. However, this property for the armor stand is useless, as it never changes even if it gets hit. How can I detect if a player hits an armor stand with this limitation in mind?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect a hit of an armor stand using an entity called the Interaction. Which in the data properties there is a property called attack and if you use `attack.timestamp` you can get the time the interaction was hit, and set a scoreboard to the timestamp, if the scoreboard is larger than 0 then do something, and after doing something you set it back to 0. You can set the scoreboard by using:

```
/execute store result score [Holder Of The Score] [Score] run data get entity @e[tag=interaction,type=interaction,limit=1] attack.timestamp 1
```